# When to use line=r and line=45 in qqplot

Tags: python, data-science, statsmodels

Can anyone tell me when do we use line='r'??

`sm.qqplot(df['Delivery_time'], line='r')`

and when do we use line=45?

`sm.qqplot(df['Delivery_time'], line='45')`

Comment: Did you try to **read the documentation**, in order to understand what these values mean?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation stats.mode](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html)l ,line can be {None, “45”, “s”, “r”, “q”}
“45” - 45-degree line
“r” - A regression line is fit

Let me add codes and output of the the two cases for better understanding.

Case 1:, if we are comparing the distribution of a sample of data to a theoretical normal distribution, we might use line='r' to plot a regression line that shows how well the sample data fits the normal distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab as py
data_points = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)   

sm.qqplot(data_points, line ='r')
py.show()
```

[image: line='r']

Case 2: If the line='45' would refer to a 45-degree line, which is a line that has a slope of 1 and passes through the origin. This line is used as a reference for comparing the distribution of the data being plotted to a uniform distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab as py
data_points = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)   

sm.qqplot(data_points, line ='45')
py.show()
```

[image: Output : ref line at 45 degrees]

For example, in the above case we are compare the distribution of a sample of data to a uniform distribution, we might use line='45' to plot a reference line that shows how well the sample data fits the uniform distribution.

Note :The line parameter can be used to customize the reference line on the Q-Q plot to better compare the distribution of the data being plotted to a theoretical distribution.